# Export css file to Django template language

Tags: css, django

I was working on a Django project on my PC and i have a Bootstrap template for my site ,
is there any simple way to convert my CSS files to Django Template Language.
is there a tool that convert it to Django Static files?!

Comment: are you trying to add bootstrap sites to django app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css, not so sure but converting HTML template to django templates you should try

> https://github.com/L4TTiCe/djangify

Answer (score 0):

ya there is one but it will take time instead of this will suggest you to edit this manually because sometimes the css and js comes from different path so you don't directly convert them

> https://github.com/danidee10/Staticfy